# ant.jar Java and Apache ant

Tags: linux, ant

linux :: Opensuse 12.3 :: installing Apache Cordova

Hi everyone! I d'like to run the command `ant` in cli but it gives me an error:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed
```

I have java installed:

```
linux-s3z2:/srv/www/htdocs/cordova # java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (suse-8.18.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)
```

and my echo $PATH looks like that

```
linux-s3z2:/srv/www/htdocs/cordova # echo $PATH
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin      /X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/home/gdia/Documents/sdk/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin/
```

So there is an "ant" file in `/home/gdia/Documents/sdk/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin/` for Apache ant, I don't understand why it's looking somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `which` command will show where `ant` is installed.

The error `Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed` means Ant is installed.

You have to run `ant` from a directory with a file named `build.xml`. See the second paragraph of [Running Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

> When no arguments are specified, Ant looks for a build.xml file in the
>   current directory and, if found, uses that file as the build file and
>   runs the target specified in the default attribute of the 
>   tag.

Comment: Thks 'Chad Nouis'. What is the proper way to install ${ANT_HOME} variable in linux I'm more use with PATH=$PATH:....

Comment: @user2327456, that's a separate question. You may find an answer elsewhere on the site.